How to implement dual authentication (email and phone number) in Django Rest Framework?
I'm building a Django Rest Framework (DRF) application and I need to implement dual authentication, allowing users to sign in using either their email or mobile number. What is the best approach to implement this?
I've already set up the authentication system using email, but now I need to extend it to support mobile number authentication as well. Should I create a custom authentication backend, or is there a DRF package that can help me achieve this more easily?
I'd appreciate any advice or examples on how to implement dual authentication in DRF. Thank you!

Edit your question to add a [example] which we can build off of.

DRF gives you login with email but if you want to login with phone number, you have to implement custom authentication for it.
if you already setup auth with email, then simply extend it with email because there's no package for it.

You can archive authentication using (email or mobile) by overriding User model like this
models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import CustomUser
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth import login

### Authentication handler
def authenticate(email_or_mobile,password):
  user = CustomUser.objects.filter(Q(email=email_or_mobile) | Q(mobile=email_or_mobile)).first()
  if user:
    is_user = check_password(password,user.password)
    if is_user:
      return user
    else: None
  else:
    return None

admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name','mobile')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', )}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('id','email','mobile', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                    'is_active', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('email',)
    
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)

Signin ApiView
class SigninApiView(APIView):
  def post(self,request):
    email_or_mobile = request.POST.get('email_or_mobile')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(email_or_mobile,password)
    if user is not None:
      login(request,user)
      return Response({'status':True,'message':'Login success'},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
      return Response({'status':False,'message':'Invalid Credentials!'},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}

admin panel

